# Making websites suitable for different resolutions

Tags: html, css, layout, resolution

as the title says. How can you alter a website so it looks the same on a, for example, 19" 1280*1024 res. monitor and a 26" 1920*1080 res. I keep having problems with different positioning as soon as they aren't centered through `margin:0 auto;`

How do you fix that? Internet ain't helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your website responsive. Try looking into the following links,

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Or you can look at plugins that help you do it. RestiveJS is an example.

http://restivejs.com

Using RestiveJS:

```
$.restive.startMulti();

$('body').restive({
      platform: 'ios', 
      breakpoints: ['240', '320', '480', '640', '960', '1024'],
      classes: ['css-i-240', 'css-i-320', 'css-i-480', 'css-i-640', 'css-i-960', 'css-i-1024']
});

$('body').restive({
      platform: 'android', 
      breakpoints: ['240', '320', '480', '640', '960', '1024'],
      classes: ['css-a-240', 'css-a-320', 'css-a-480', 'css-a-640', 'css-a-960', 'css-a-1024']
});

$.restive.endMulti();
```

Restive.JS will actively monitor the viewports of any devices that visit your web site for the following width ranges: 0 to 240px, 241 to 320px, 321 to 480px, 481 to 640px, 641 to 960px, and 961 to 1024px; and the following device platforms: iOS and Android. If the viewport is between 481 and 640 pixels wide, and the device is an iOS device e.g. iPhone 4, it will add the class css-i-640 to the  tag; if the viewport is between 641 and 960 pixels wide, and the device is an Android device e.g. Nexus 4, it will add the class css-a-960, and so on.

It's not so hard to learn, you will be able to implement it quickly..

Comment: thanks looks interesting though they dont really show the stylesheet. and the plugin says you need JS knowledge. which i dont have all too much at the moment. the media rules option looks appealing at the moment. Unless you can explain it better than w3schools does so i understand how it works?  would like to accept this answer (especially because it doesnt show if something needs to be in a certain position aka small links for example that arent centered)

Comment: well im just starting with JS (and java) but having quite a hard time understanding it. the elaboration i was asking was regarding the responsive html. 
I think the JS support will do a better job. I'll see where i go from there. Need to see how it "breaks" my website on my htc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "CSS3 Media Rules" I think this could be what you're looking for.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: great! wonder why i never got that from google when asking it... 
this means i need a stylesheet for each common resolution / screensize right? seems like a hastle to be honest. isn't there a more "straight forward" way? (with all these devices and sizes i would have 15 stylesheets and more....)

Comment: You could put it all in one stylesheet if that was an issue depending on how many styles you needed to change. Usually you would only need 3 sizes of screen (desktop, tablet, mobile) to make things look neat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into using liquid layouts, where instead of using px or pt you use percentages, for example you could set the header div height to 20% of the screen

http://maxdesign.com.au/news/liquid/

Comment: his links are not working anymore. i think he moved to wordpress. i will have a deeper look in that topic though thanks